# How do you access cloud storage images via local GAE development server?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, localhost, google-cloud-storage

I can't figure out how to generate image urls in the local development server. In production I can use

```
CloudStorageTools::getImageServingUrl("gs://example/path/to/image.jpg")
```

but when I use the same line using the development server, it generates

```
http://localhost:24080/_ah/img/encoded_gs_file:d2lsZHN0YXItZGF0YS9pbWFnZXMvdGVzdC9tZTMuanBlZw==
```

instead of a actual url to a image. I'll have a large set of images and they are best suited to be stored with cloud stage instead of the app engine app.

Answer (score 0):

The local dev_appserver uses local file system to emulate GCS. That's why the URL you get from getImageServingUrl only works on your local machine. You'll get a publicly accessible URL when running the app in production.

Comment: Right now the image is returning a 405 error:

`curl -iI     http://localhost:24080/_ah/img/encoded_gs_file:d2lsZHN0YXItZGF0YS9pbWFnZXMvdGVzdC9tZTMuanBlZw==
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Server: Development/2.0
Connection: close
Date: Fri, 16 May 2014 04:38:49 GMT`

Is that expected? Can I place the images somewhere on my local system to emulate GCS better?

Comment: The local dev_appserver does not support HTTP HEAD method (which is implied by the -I flag for curl). Try open the link in any browser and you should see the image.